# Expresión regular "test" siempre retorna falso

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Buenas tardes tengo el siguiente código, pero no logró hacer la siguiente válidación, necesito que en una etiqueta `<div>` muestre el mensaje **"bien"** o **"mal"**.

```js
$(document).on("keyup", "input#txt-codigo-doc",function () {
    var soloNumero =/[^0-9]+$/g;
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(soloNumero,''));
    if(soloNumero.test($(this).val())){
        $("div#mensaje-codigo-doc").html("bien");
    }else{
        $("div#mensaje-codigo-doc").html("mal");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txt-codigo-doc">
<div id="mensaje-codigo-doc"></div>
```

Al ejecutar el código siempre me retorna el mensaje **"mal"**, nose porque sale siempre el mismo mensaje si la condición debe cumplirse.
Necesito ayuda para solucionar este problema, **como siempre cualquier ayuda es bienvenida.**

Comment: ¿Y, qué es lo que tiene que ocurrir para que salga `bien`?

Comment: En esta línea `$(this).val($(this).val().replace(soloNumero,''));` tú evitas que el input reciba otra cosa diferente de números (prueba a escribir una letra por ejemplo), por tanto nunca se podrá escribir algo para que se imprima la palabra `bien`. Por favor, explica con claridad qué es lo que quieres hacer realmente.

Comment: Hola @A.Cedano primero gracias por responder a esta pregunta, lo que se quiere como resultado es que al ingresar `números` en la etiqueta `<div>` debe mostrar **"bien"** y si se ingresa `letras` debe mostrar **"mal"**, pero la condición no se cumple.

Comment: No se cumple por esto: `$(this).val($(this).val().replace(soloNumero,''));` si quieres comenta esa línea y verás que funciona como esperas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se cumple porque en esta línea:

```
$(this).val($(this).val().replace(soloNumero,''));
```

estás evitando que el input reciba letras u otros caracteres que no sean numéricos.

Si la quitas, funcionará como esperas.

Por otra parte, la condición estaba al revés, según lo afirmado en tu comentario:

> lo que se quiere como resultado es que al ingresar números en la
>   etiqueta `<div>` debe mostrar "bien" y si se ingresa letras debe
>   mostrar "mal"

```js
$(document).on("keyup", "input#txt-codigo-doc",function () {
    var soloNumero = /[^0-9]+$/g;
    if(soloNumero.test($(this).val())){
        $("div#mensaje-codigo-doc").html("mal");
    }else{
        $("div#mensaje-codigo-doc").html("bien");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txt-codigo-doc">
<div id="mensaje-codigo-doc"></div>
```

---

#### Evitando un código demasiado *verboso*

Cabe decir que puedes hacer uso de un operador ternario para asignar el valor `bien`o `mal` a una variable y luego cambiar el `div` con ese valor. Algo así:

```js
$(document).on("keyup", "input#txt-codigo-doc",function () {
    var soloNumero =/[^0-9]+$/g;
    var mText=(soloNumero.test($(this).val())) ? "mal" : "bien";
    $("div#mensaje-codigo-doc").html(mText);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txt-codigo-doc">
<div id="mensaje-codigo-doc"></div>
```

Comment: Es correcto, pero modifica `/[^0-9]+$/g` a `/^[0-9]+$/g` tal como lo defines en el comentario de arriba para que corra correctamente.

Comment: @DanielR.Anccasi el comentario al respecto no es mío. Y si lo que quieres es lo que comentaste antes: *que cada vez que se escriba un número imprima `bien` y si no es un número que se imprima `mal`*, la expresión está bien así, puesta del otro modo sugerido, si pruebas una secuencia como esta: `1a5` al escribir el cinco se quedará imprimendo `mal`. Haz la prueba. Sin embargo, así como está funciona del modo que esperas, si he entendido bien. Revisa la respuesta editada y mi sugerencia sobre la *verbosidad* del código. Saludos.

Comment: @A.Cedano La expresión `/[^0-9]+$/g` valida que no haya numeros al final, por lo que una cadena como "hola4" valida, y no debería, para solucionar eso la expresión debería ser algo como  `^/[^0-9]+/g`, la expresión que había pasado yo en los comentarios era para utilizar el `.replace`.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que intentabas hacer entiendo que es un `.replace` para que ni siquiera se muestre todo lo que no es número, uno de los problemas es la expresión, que debería ser `/([^0-9])/g` (todo lo que no es número se reemplaza por nada) En lugar de `[^0-9]+$` que evalua si hay un no numero al final.

Otro tema es que hecho así, al hacer el `.test` despues de un `.replace` debería validar siempre, porque estamos transformando el string, por ello podemos guardarlo en una variable para evaluar el string antes del `.replace`, pero así tampoco tiene mucho sentido, porque lo que evaluamos en realidad es si presiona una tecla incorrecta, lo que no tiene mucho sentido, Ejemplo:

```js
$(document).on("keyup", "input#txt-codigo-doc",function () {
    var soloNumero =/([^0-9])/g;
    var value = $(this).val();
    $(this).val(value.replace(soloNumero,''));
    
    //Al hacer replace no tiene mucho sentido hacer esto
    
    if(!soloNumero.test(value)){
        $("div#mensaje-codigo-doc").html("la última tecla presionada ES un número");
    }else{
        $("div#mensaje-codigo-doc").html("la última tecla presionada NO ES un número");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txt-codigo-doc">
<div id="mensaje-codigo-doc"></div>
```

En cada evento `keyup` el `value` del input es remplazado, es por eso que en relidad evaluamos la última tecla, el último `keyup`.